# Dúvida com LoadBalance e CircuitBreaker em Microserviços

Tags: java, spring, cloud, microsserviços

Eu possuo uma estrutura de serviços da seguinte maneira:
server (Eureka),
imovel (eureka-client) e
cliente (eureka-client).

O seviço de cliente faz uma requisição para o serviço de imovel, utilizando o feign.
Eu possuo o LoadBalancer configurado nos dois lados (imóvel e cliente).
Se todos os serviços estão em execução, as chamadass e o LoadBalancer funcionam corretamente. Porém, comecei a fazer a parte do Circuitbreaker (Hystrix).

Eu subi apenas o serviço do server (eureka) e o serviço do cliente, para testar o CircuitBreaker.
Quando o serviço de cliente foi fazer uma requisição para o serviço de imóvel, o fallback foi ativado corretamente, porém, a exceção lançada foi diferente da do esperado. A exceção que recebi foi:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: imovel-service
```

Eu esperava receber uma exceção do tipo 400+. O que estou fazendo de errado?

server (Eureka Server)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class ServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.yml do server

```
server:
port: ${PORT:8080}

spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-service
  boot:
    admin:
      url: http://localhost:8090

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/


management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

Serviço CLIENTE:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@RibbonClient(name = "ribbon-configuration", configuration = RibbonConfiguration.class)
public class ClienteApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClienteApplication.class, args);
    }

    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    RestTemplate restTemplate(){
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
@Configuration
public class FeignConfiguration {

    int FIVE_SECONDS = 5000; // milliseconds

    @Bean
    Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.FULL;
    }

    @Bean
    public Request.Options options() {
        return new Request.Options(FIVE_SECONDS, FIVE_SECONDS);
    }
}

@FeignClient(value = "imovel-service", fallbackFactory = ImovelClientFallBackFactory.class)
public interface ImovelClient {

    @GetMapping("/imovel")
    List<Imovel> findAll();

    @GetMapping("/imovel/{id}")
    Imovel find(@PathVariable("id") Integer id);
}

@Component
public class ImovelClientFallBackFactory implements FallbackFactory<ImovelClient> {

    @Override
    public ImovelClient create(Throwable throwable) {
        return new ImovelClientFallBack(throwable);
    }

    public class ImovelClientFallBack implements ImovelClient {

        private final Throwable cause;

        public ImovelClientFallBack(Throwable cause) {
            this.cause = cause;
        }

        @Override
        public List<Imovel> findAll() {
            if (cause instanceof FeignException && ((FeignException) cause).status() == 404) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Serviço indisponível!");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Imovel find(Integer id) {
            if (cause instanceof FeignException && ((FeignException) cause).status() == 404) { --aqui não vem 404, vem a exceção que comentei logo acima.
                throw new RuntimeException("Serviço indisponível!");
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

application.yml do CLIENTE

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:8082}

#LOCALIZAÇÃO DO EUREKA SERVER
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8080/eureka}
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true

spring:
  application:
    name: cliente-service

#CONFIGURAÇÃO DE FALLBACK DO FEIGN
feign:
  hystrix:
    enabled: true

imovel-service:
  ribbon:
    MaxAutoRetries: 3
    retryableStatusCodes: 404
```

O serviço IMOVEL tem as mesmas configurações, exceto o application.yml

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:8081}

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8080/eureka}
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true

spring:
  application:
    name: imovel-service
```

Porque estou recebendo a exceção de LoadBalancer e não de 404?

Comment: Alguém poderia ajudar?!

Comment: Esta é a forma que o feign client lida com o balanceamento das requisições em conjunto com o Eureka, ou seja, o feign client foi buscar no eureka a aplicação imovel-service e não a encontrou. Portanto, o erro retornado está de acordo com o funcionamento do framework. Você não recebera 404 porque a API do eureka existe e você pediu por um serviço que existe, porém não tem nenhuma instância disponível. Portanto, recebeu a exceção que não encontrou nenhum endpoint disponível.